# Where do I get a 7-zip install package that isn't an executable file?

Tags: 7-zip

I remember a previous option where you could download a zip file containing everything you need to run 7-zip.

Now all the download page has is executable files, msi (Microsoft installer framework for Windows), and .7z packages of extras.

Where's the option to "install from extracted zip file"?

Comment: Are you asking how you download an 7-zip installation contained in an archive?  Honestly your question is confusing

Comment: Just go to [7Zip][1] this website. Download the file and install it. No, extra packages are required.


  [1]: http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: Who unarchives the unarchiver?

Comment: You can use 7zip or WinRar to extract the exe file as if it was a zip without running it.

Comment: Install 7-Zip on one computer, then copy everything from `%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip`.

Comment: @SpiderPig's comment seems to actually answer the question, unlike iBug's comment and answer and Biku Balami's comment.  Hey!  SpiderPig!  Copy the text of that comment and paste it into a the "Your Answer" field.  If you'd have done that already, you likely would have received an up-vote by now.  You might also want to mention both 7-zip.org and http://sf.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip

Comment: This is funny. I had exactly the same question. Is there a zip-file (not installer exe) containing the 7-zip program directory, that has only to be extracted to use it? I cannot understand, that this leads to so much confusion.

Answer (score 11):

So you want to avoid having to install it? Luckily the installer exe is just a 7z file bundled with an unpacker so you can just extract it.

First go to http://www.7-zip.org/download.html and download the exe for the latest version (http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1801-x64.exe). Also you should download the command line version of 7zip 9.2 which you can get as a zip (http://www.7-zip.org/a/7za920.zip).

After unpacking 7za920.zip you can extract 7z1801-x64.exe from the command line with `7za x -o7zip 7z1801-x64.exe`

Comment: How do you open it if you don't already have 7-zip?

Comment: With the command line version of 7zip. (http://www.7-zip.org/a/7za920.zip)

Comment: Even in 2020 this answer still works with the latest 7z1900-x64.exe version.  Thanks for the great help, operating without admin rights is a headache.

Answer (score 0):

No need to ask for help.

Go to the website and download 7-Zip: http://www.7-zip.org

Then install it. By default the program installs to `%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip`.

After that, you just copy (or archive) everything from that directory, which can be used as a "standalone" archiver. Thing you'll lose from that are system integration features like the right-click menu items and file type association.

Comment: He clearly asked **where** to get a 7zip application that is not in a executable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the "portable" version of the program, that is one that can even be executed once burned on a CD. You can find many of them at the [portable apps site](https://portableapps.com/).
For the 7zip program, the [>instructions](https://portableapps.com/support/7-zip_portable#cd) say that you still have to "install" it once to extract the program parts and set the configuration file how you want, but that the resulting executable (and its config file) can then be redistributed as it is

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did,

1. downloaded their oldest command line archive (7-Zip 9.20 (2010-11-18) for Windows)
2. the latest 7-Zip 19.00 (2019-02-21) for Windows (.exe) version.
3. The zip can be opened with normal Windows Explorer, and copied the 7za.exe to a different folder
4. Open the command prompt run `<path to 7za.exe> x <path to the latest .exe>` that unpacks the exe
5. Now you can run the GUI version from path where you have extracted (your current folder).

To all others who is asking about the need for this.. The exe or the msi are packaged as installers, which require admin access on windows. The actual 7zip file manager does not need admin access as long as you want to run as an app and don't worry about adding explorer context menus. Previously they used to publish a simple zip with all artifacts, which can be run as standard user. Now you need to go through this procedure to get it.